# $H_{0}^{1}(\Omega)\hookrightarrow L^4(\Omega)$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

In a paper I see that the authors used $H_{0}^{1}(\Omega)\hookrightarrow L^4(\Omega)$ where $\Omega$ is an open bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^N$ with smooth boundary. I think that this imbedding holds only for those $N$ which satisfy $4\leq 2^\star$($2^\star=\frac{2N}{N-2}$) i.e. when $\Omega$ is in $\mathbb{R}^3$ or $\mathbb{R}^4$. How we can show this imbedding for higher dimensions?

Comment: You are right, this is only true for $N\le 4$.

Comment: @daw Thank you very much. I do think so.

Answer (score 1):

The general result is called the Sobolev embedding theorem, which states that $H_0^k$ is embedded in $L^q$ where $$\frac{1}{q}=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{k}{n}$$ where $n$ is the dimension of the space. This can be generalized even further, see the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_inequality) article.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I know the generalized form of the Sobolev imbedding. But my question is in this special case $k=1$.